# How to set TCP SEQ number generation

Tags: tcp, nmap

There is a Windows 2000 system, that when I scanned it, it said, that the TCP SEQ number prediction is really low (nmap – trivial joke).

While I'm still trying to verify that, I wondered, how could I set the TCP SEQ number generation myself? Is there an option somewhere that I can change, or is that usually hard-coded, and therefore only changeable with changing source code and recompiling?

Comment: The answer to this will depend entirely on the operating system in question. Please give more detail in your question. Also note that another term for TCP SEQ number generation is TCP Initial Sequence Number (ISN) generation. This may help you in researching the question.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The algorithm is buried deep in the TCP/IP stack's code.

Comment: And how can get to that algorithm?